# value is changing when storing in state

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am having this really weird issue where when I store a value in state, it is changing value.

I'm using a time picker from Antd, and when I select a time, it triggers an `onChange` called `startTimeSelected` that parses out the total minutes and hours of the time selected (eg 8:00 would be 8hrs and 0 mins), and then converts it to minutes (`totalStartMins`), and then stores it in state as `totalStartM`. But when I console log the values of `totalStartMins` and `totalStartM`, the values differ. Any ideas why would be really helpful.

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/time-picker-error-xvo4v?file=/src/Row.js) with the code, note that you can't actually test it out I'm not sure why (I think CodeSandbox x Antd issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have console logged just after you set your state. And setting the state is an async task, that is why you are not getting your updated value in your state.

Your state value is perfectly fine.

To test this, you can simply add `<p>{totalStartM}</p>` in your return function.

Or you can use **useEffect** hook to do so as well.

```
useEffect(() => { console.log('Testing startM value', totalStartM) }, [totalStartM])
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I had no idea setting the state is an async task. Thanks!

Comment: No worries @aminicam. Reach out if there is anything. Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use hooks, and do

```
const [totalStartM, setTotalStartM] = useState(0);
```

when you do:

```
const startTimeSelected = (time, timeString) => {
    // ...
    setTotalStartM(totalStartMins);
    console.log(totalStartM);
};
```

you have to remember that `totalStartM` won't be updated until the next time the component renders.

https://codesandbox.io/s/time-picker-error-forked-z3vfm